# An equivalent characterization of the first chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be a projective algebraic manifold. *92' Singular hermitian metrics on positive line bundles  demailly* wrote:

An integral cohomology class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the first Chern class of a holomorphic (or algebraic) line bundle if and only if this class is of type (1, 1).

Qustion: How to prove the above claim ? Or where can I get the detailed proof ?

Comment: This is known as the [Lefschetz theorem on $(1, 1)$ classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_theorem_on_(1,1)-classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the combination of the following two theorems, which can all be found in Griffiths and Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geomtry*:

1. Lefschetz $(1,1)$ theorem, i.e., classes in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb C)$ can be represented by Poincare duality of divisors (page 163).
2. If the line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ is defined by a divisor $D$, then its first Chern class $c_1(\mathcal{L})$ is the Poincare duality of $D$ (page 141, Prop. 2).